# ¿Cómo funcionan los apuntadores?

Tags: c

Disculpen tengo que hacer un programa en C que pida el numero de vehiculos que participaran en una carrera que sea entre el 1-10 y ingrese el tiempo de salida y llegada de cada uno y se guarde en un vector salida[10], llegada[10] y haga la resta de esos 2 para poder calcular cual fue el ganador de la carrera pero tengo que usar apuntadores y no se mucho sobre ese tema por eso no se como arreglar mi codigo, esta bien hasta la parte de

```
for(i=0;i<c;i++){
        dif[i]=llegada[i]-salida[i];
        if(dif[i]<aux){
            dif[i]=*auxx;
            s++;
        }
    }
    *auxx=s;
        printf("\nel ganador es: %d \n", s);

    return 0;
}
```

me podrian explicar como usar apuntadores en mi codigo y si me podrian brindar un libro o pagina donde pueda aprender sobre apuntadores seria de mucha ayuda por favor

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    int salida[10],llegada[10], dif[10];
    int c, i, s, count=0, aux=9999999, *auxx;

    printf("¿cuantos vehiculos participaran en la carrera? \n");
    scanf("%d",&c);
    if(c>10){
        printf("sorry bro :v solo 10 vehiculos pueden participar en la carrera\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    else if(c<=0){
        printf("debes ingresar un numero de vehiculos del 1 al 10\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    else
    printf("\nkuchau we :v\n\n");
    printf("\n--------LA HORA DE SALIDA Y LLEGADA DEBEN SER INTRODUCIDAS EN SEGUNDOS--------\n\n");
    for(i=0;i<c;i++){
        printf("ingresa la hora de salida del vehiculo %d: \n", count+1);
        scanf("%d",&salida[i]);
        printf("ingresa la hora de llegada del vehiculo %d \n", count+1);
        scanf("%d",&llegada[i]);
        count++;
    }
    printf("los datos se han ingresado correctamente");
    for(i=0;i<c;i++){
        dif[i]=llegada[i]-salida[i];
        if(dif[i]<aux){
            dif[i]=*auxx;
            s++;
        }
    }
    *auxx=s;
        printf("\nel ganador es: %d \n", s);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Los apuntadores (o *punteros* como los llamaré de ahora en adelante), son clave en el manejo de referencias a variables alocadas en la memoria principal durante la ejecución de tu programa.

Para esto, recordemos que **un puntero es una variable cuyo contenido es la dirección de memoria de otra variable**.

Esta dirección de memoria puede ser obtenida utilizando el caracter `&`, seguido del nombre de la variable. Así, `&a`, `&aux` y `&total` representan las direcciones de memoria de las variables `a`, `aux` y `total`, respectivamente.

Un puntero es declarado en C del siguiente modo:

```
tipoDeDato *nombreDelPuntero;
```

También puedes hacer la asignación directamente, siempre teniendo en cuenta que el tipo de dato del puntero debe coincidir con el tipo de dato de la variable a la cual vas a referenciar. Así, por ejemplo:

```
int a = 2;
int *alpha = &a;
```

Esto hará que la variable `alpha` referencie el contenido de la variable `a` a través de su dirección de memoria. Utilizando este puntero, podemos realizar llamadas o cambios a la variable `a` sin necesidad de pasarla explícitamente como argumento a funciones dentro de nuestro programa (lo que se conoce como *paso por valor*), y en lugar de eso, pasar únicamente el puntero que hace referencia a esa variable (lo que se conoce como *paso por referencia*). Toda modificación realizada al puntero dentro de la función, afectará de forma indirecta a la variable cuya dirección de memoria se encuentre almacenada en este puntero.

Para acceder al contenido de la variable referenciada por un puntero, basta con colocar un `*` previo al nombre del puntero. Si queremos acceder a la dirección de memoria que almacena el puntero, utilizamos únicamente el nombre del puntero. Para nuestro ejemplo anterior:

```
print(*alpha); //esto imprime el valor actual de la variable a
print(alpha); //esto imprime la dirección de memoria de la variable a
```

Un uso muy común de los punteros es para referenciar bloques de memoria asignados de manera dinámica. En C esto se hace a través de la función `malloc()` (o `calloc()`, pero por ahora no veremos eso). Un ejemplo de asignación dinámica de memoria es el siguiente:

```
char *c = malloc(sizeof (char));
*c = 'f';
printf("Caracter ingresado: %c", *c);
```

Se alocará, en la memoria principal durante la ejecución de tu programa, el espacio suficiente para contener al tipo de dato que pasaste como parámetro en `sizeof`. En este caso, `char`.

Con esto, puedes crear *arreglos dinámicos*. Muy diferentes a los arreglos estáticos a los que estás acostumbrado. En tu caso:

```
int salida[10], llegada[10], dif[10];
```

pueden ser redefinidos como arreglos de memoria dinámica utilizando `malloc()`. Una vez tu usuario inserte el número de competidores, es posible realizar esta asignación para reservar exactamente la cantidad de memoria que necesitas. Primero, realizas la declaración de punteros al comienzo del programa. Es decir:

```
int c, i, s = 0, count = 0, aux = 9999999, *auxx, *salida, *llegada, *dif;
```

Y los inicializas una vez el usuario inserte la cantidad de vehículos participantes en la carrera. En este caso:

```
//...

else{
    printf("\nkuchau we :v\n\n");
    salida = malloc(sizeof(int)*c); //donde c es la cantidad de competidores
    llegada = malloc(sizeof(int)*c);
    dif = malloc(sizeof(int)*c);
}

//...
```

Puedes iterar a través de estos arreglos dinámicos utilizando un bucle de repetición (`for`) como si se tratara de arreglos estáticos convencionales. La forma en cómo accedes a cada elemento es similar, y entonces:

```
for(i=0;i<c;i++){
    printf("ingresa la hora de salida del vehiculo %d: \n", count+1);
    scanf("%d",&salida[i]);
    printf("ingresa la hora de llegada del vehiculo %d \n", count+1);
    scanf("%d",&llegada[i]);
    count++;
}
```

Finalmente, echemos un vistazo a la última porción de tu código. Como podrás darte cuenta, hay un par de errores que cometes aquí:

```
for(i=0;i<c;i++){
    dif[i]=llegada[i]-salida[i];
    if(dif[i]<aux){
        dif[i]=*auxx;
        s++;
    }
}

*auxx=s;

printf("\nel ganador es: %d \n", s);
```

El primero, es que cuando ya comienzas a obtener cada elemento del arreglo de diferencias de tiempo y lo comparas con `aux`, podrás darte cuenta que el puntero `*auxx` nunca fue asignado a ninguna dirección de memoria en primer lugar. Esto, sumado al hecho de que estás asignándole el valor de este puntero a cada elemento del vector diferencia que sea menor a `aux` (comportamiento no deseado, puesto que ya sacas `dif[i]` previamente, y quieres utilizar ese valor mas no redefinirlo).

Esto puede corregirse inicializando `*auxx` debidamente. Este puntero será el encargado de modificar el valor de la variable `aux` a la que está referenciando cada vez que la diferencia sea menor al valor actual de `aux` (de nuevo, referenciado a través del puntero `*auxx`). Al final del bucle, `aux` tendrá el valor de diferencia del ganador, accesible mediante el puntero `*auxx` (puedes también llamar a `aux` al momento de mostrar la diferencia de tiempo del vehículo ganador) y `s` contendrá el número del vehículo ganador:

```
int c, i, s = 0, count = 0, aux = 9999999, *auxx, *salida, *llegada, *dif;

*auxx = &aux; //aquí

//...

for(i=0;i<c;i++){
    dif[i]=llegada[i]-salida[i];
    if(dif[i]<*auxx){
        *auxx = dif[i];
        s++;
    }
}
printf("\nEl ganador es %d, con una diferencia de %d segundos! \n", s, *auxx);
```

Si quieres revisar más sobre punteros y alocación de memoria dinámica, te aconsejo revisar el siguiente enlace:

- https://www.tutorialesprogramacionya.com/cya/detalleconcepto.php?punto=37&codigo=37&inicio=30

Comment: Listo, editado con correcciones al código (incluso arrojé el fix a la última parte). Espero haya podido ser de ayuda.

Comment: Un tema religioso: [Castear el resultado de `malloc` al tipo de destino puede ser peligroso.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20094422/5622844) :)