# ¿Por qué se habla de dirección de memoria cuando se trata de punteros?

Tags: c++, c

Tomando como fuente una parte de la respuesta: [¿Cómo funcionan los apuntadores?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/66099/c%c3%b3mo-funcionan-los-apuntadores), observo que especifican lo siguiente:

> Un puntero es una variable cuyo contenido es la dirección de memoria de otra variable
>
> Esta dirección de memoria puede ser obtenida utilizando el caracter &, seguido del nombre de la variable. Así, &a, &aux y &total representan las direcciones de memoria de las variables a, aux y total, respectivamente.*"

¿Por qué se dice que es una de dirección de memoria cuando no se especifica por ejemplo 0x002, 0x010, etc?

Comment: Lo siento pero la pregunta no la termino de entender

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con el texto en negrita?

Comment: ¿Que por qué? ... Trata de dereferenciar un puntero que apunte a la dirección `x010`, luego nos cuentas cómo fue la violación del segmento.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Un puntero es una variable cuyo valor es una dirección de memoria. Las direcciones de memoria pueden entenderse como una especie de índice entero si imaginas que la memoria completa es como un array de bytes.

Efectivamente podrías inicializar un puntero asignándole directamente una dirección (y la costumbre es especificarla en hexadecimal, pero podrías escribirla también en base 10), como en el ejemplo siguiente:

```
char *puntero;

puntero = 0x00001234;
// o puntero = 4460;  que es lo mismo en este caso
```

Sin embargo nunca se inicializa un puntero de esa forma porque no sabes a priori si la dirección a la que le haces apuntar ya está siendo ocupada por otra variable, o código, o es una dirección protegida a la que está prohibido el acceso.

Cuando intentas usar el dato contenido en esa dirección (poniendo un `*` delante del puntero), la CPU intentará acceder a esa dirección de memoria. Por ejemplo, en el caso siguiente intentará escribir un byte con el código ascii de la ‘a’ en esa dirección:

```
*puntero = 'a';
```

El resultado más probable es que esa dirección esté protegida y el intento de escribir en ella sea impedido por el sistema operativo, que abortará tu programa con un *segmentation fault*. Pero podría ser peor... podría ser que esa dirección pertenezca a una zona de datos de tu programa y estés cambiando el valor de una variable “sin saberlo”.

La forma correcta de inicializar un puntero no es asignarle una dirección “a pelo”, sino darle la dirección de otra variable preexistente, o de una zona libre en el *heap*.

Para el primer caso se usa `&` delante del nombre de otra variable:

```
char variable;
char *puntero;

puntero = &variable;
*puntero = 'a';
```

Ahora la dirección que hemos guardado en `puntero` es la que está ocupando la variable `variable`. Cuando metemos la ‘a’ en esa dirección, estaremos modificando el valor de `variable`, pero al menos lo hacemos intencionadamente y no por error.

El puntero en sí mismo sigue siendo un número como cuando lo inicializamos “a pelo”. Puedes comprobarlo imprimiendo su valor con `printf("%p", puntero)`, y verás obviamente lo mismo que si pones `printf("%p", &variable)`.

La otra forma de inicializarlo consiste en pedir al operativo una zona libre de memoria del tamaño necesario (en este caso 1 byte) y asignarle al puntero la dirección que nos sea retornada. Así:

```
char *puntero;
puntero = malloc(1*sizeof(char));  // 1 byte
*puntero = 'a';
```

`malloc()` busca una zona de bytes contiguos que esté libre, la marca como reservada para tí, y te retorna la dirección en que comienza esa zona. Si imprimes el valor del puntero como antes puedes ver qué dirección ha sido (si no puede encontrar memoria libre te retornará  `NULL` que es el valor especial 0). La zona donde `malloc()` busca se denomina el *heap* o *montón*, y tiene un rango de direcciones diferente a las zonas donde suelen estar las variables del programa.

En resumen, las direcciones de memoria son realmente números, como tú correctamente habías entendido, pero no suelen asignarse directamente esos números, sino obtenerse indirectamente bien de las direcciones en que están otras variables (operador `&`) o del *heap* a través de `malloc()`.

### Actualización

Olvidé comentar en lo anterior que la memoria que hayas reservado con `malloc()` es específica del proceso que la solicitó. Cuando ese proceso termina, la memoria es liberada. También puedes liberarla "manualmente" cuando no vayas a necesitarla más, mediante `free(puntero);`. De hecho, esto es lo que hay que hacer cuando has hecho `malloc()` dentro de una función, para asignar el resultado a un puntero local de la función, pues de no hacer `free()` antes de que la función retorne, esa memoria quedará ocupada (y lo que es peor, el puntero que apuntaba a ella se destruirá al finalizar la función por lo que ese trozo de memoria queda inaccesible y ya no puede liberarse hasta que el programa termine). Este error da lugar a los (tristemente) famosos *memory leaks* o "fugas de memoria", que es un *bug* en ocasiones difícil de corregir, que tiene el efecto de que la memoria ocupada por un proceso va creciendo sin necesidad conforme el proceso pasa más tiempo en ejecución.

En C++, la función `malloc()` sigue estando disponible, pero se desaconseja su uso por ser de demasiado bajo nivel (la cantidad de memoria a reservar hay que especificarla en número de bytes, el puntero retornado no tiene un tipo concreto, por lo que podríamos intentar usarlo después de formas inconsistentes, la memoria recién reservada no está inicializada en forma alguna, etc.)

La forma correcta de reservar memoria en el *heap* en C++ es utilizar el operador `new`, como por ejemplo:

```
int *puntero;
puntero = new int;
```

Una vez reservado, el puntero se usa como en C:

```
*puntero = 100;  // Guarda un 100 en la dirección apuntada
std::cout << *puntero << std::endl;  // Muestra 100
std::cout << puntero << std::endl;   // Muestra la dirección a que apunta, p.ej: 0xc7cc20
```

Si el tipo a que apunta el puntero es una clase, el operador `new`, además de reservar memoria, llamará al constructor de la clase para inicializar el objeto recién creado.

Al igual que en C, es necesario recordar liberar la memoria que hayas reservado cuando ya no es necesaria o vayas a retornar de la función que la usaba (y no necesites retornar el puntero, claro). En el caso de C++, si la memoria la obtuviste con `new`, debes usar `delete puntero` (en lugar de `free(puntero)`. Cuando usas `delete puntero`, si el puntero apuntaba a un objeto se llamará al destructor de ese objeto antes de liberar la memoria en que estaba almacenado.

Comment: Ya que la pregunta incluye la etiqueta `c++`, sería bueno que incluyas como se puede pedir una zona libre de memoria en C++.

Comment: @Xam, buena idea, gracias. Respuesta actualizada.

Comment: @abulafia Excelente explicación. A ver si entendí bien: un puntero es un apuntador hacia una dirección específica de la memoria que queremos modificar ¿también se usa para leer?, pero esa dirección debe ser la de una variable preexistente porque podría provocar una violación de acceso.
¿Esto quiere decir que si asignamos una variable "a", el sistema operativo escribe el byte en una dirección de memoria libre para el usuario, y al utilizar un puntero, el sistema operativo lee la dirección de memoria de la variable y escribe el nuevo valor que se le ha asignado?

Comment: @Morganmariano Sí, un puntero puede usarse para leer la dirección a que apunta si lo usas en una expresión precedido de `*`, por ejemplo, valor = *puntero;`. Respecto al resto de tu consulta, no es exactamente como dices. Cuando declaras una variable, depende de si la variable es global o local. Las variables globales son todas creadas cuando el operativo carga tu programa en memoria y coexisten en una zona de la memoria llamada "segmento de datos". Si son locales, existen en otra zona llamada "pila" que es creada cuando se llama a la función y eliminada cuando la función termina.

Comment: @Morganmariano Finalmente las variables creadas dinámicamente con `malloc()` o `new` existen en una tercera zona (el _heap_) que es una zona asignada por el operativo a tu programa cuando lo pides y que no se libera automáticamente (requiere `free` o `delete`). Quien escribe en esas direcciones de memoria es la propia CPU siguiendo las instrucciones de tu programa. El operativo no interviene a menos que la CPU intente escribir/leer en una dirección protegida. Mientas el programa lea de sus propias variables (globales o locales, u obtenidas del _heap_ vía `malloc()`) el operativo no interviene.

Answer (score 1):

No hay diferencia entre un numero entero cualquiera y una direccion de memoria, todas estas asignaciones son validas:

```
void * a = 1;
int    b = 1;
void * c = 0x01;
int    d = 0x01;
```

En todos los casos se esta asignando un valor entero a una variable, la diferencia es que en los punteros se asume que su valor representa una direccion de memoria, no importa como este descrito este valor. Sin embargo si intentas hacer una asignacion de esta forma el compilador te dara la siguiente advertencia:

> aviso: la inicialización crea un puntero desde un entero sin una
>   conversión [-Wint-conversion]   void * a = 1;
>
> aviso: la inicialización crea un puntero desde un entero sin una
>   conversión [-Wint-conversion]   void * c = 0x01;

Ya que por lo general no se puede predecir que va a haber en una direccion especifica.

Answer (score 0):

Es posible hacer una asignacion a una direccion particular de la memoria si se programa con sistemas embeidos de la siguiente manera.

volatile int *puntero = mi_direccion;

Sin embargo los sistemas operativos usualmente no hacen uso directo de la "memoria fisica" de un computador en cambio usan una tecnica llamada memoria virtual la cual segun las necesidades mapea hacia una direccion fisica de memoria, esto con la intencion de tener un manejo mas eficiente de los recursos del computador.

Dicha memoria virtual esta segmentada en dos "espacios de memoria" uno para el kernel y otro para el usuario, el espacio de memoria de usuario que es donde usualmente corre tu programa el cual no permite el uso directo de la memoria a travez de una direccion fisica.