# duda con malloc

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>  
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(){

   int *pi;
   pi=malloc(sizeof(int));
   *pi=5;
   printf("%d\n",*pi);
   pi=5;
   printf("%d\n",pi);
   puts("");

   char *cadena;
   cadena=malloc(5*sizeof(char));
   cadena="hola";
   printf("%s\n",cadena);

   return 0;
}
```

Tengo una duda y es en el `*pi=5` y `pi=5`, ¿cual debería usarse? ¿Porque funcionan los dos?

Se que con cadena si la intento desreferenciar se producirá un error o sea que no podría hacer `*cadena="hola"` sin embargo con `*pi=5` si puedo y no se produce error.

Y por otra parte ¿El código es correcto?

> Creo que quedaria tal que asi, gracias @abulafia y @NaCI por vuestra ayuda:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(){

   int *pi=malloc(sizeof(int));
   if(!pi){
      puts("no se pudo asignar memoria dinamica");
      exit(-1);
   }
   *pi=5;
   printf("%d\n",*pi);
   free(pi);
   pi=NULL;

   char *cadena=malloc(5);
   if(!cadena){
      puts("no se pudo asignar memoria dinamica");
      exit(-1);
   }
   sprintf(cadena, "%s", "hola");
   printf("%s\n",cadena);
   free(cadena);
   cadena=NULL;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Mira a ver si [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/144395/7123) te lo aclara.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Empecemos por lo básico:

- [`malloc(size_t)`](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malloc): Es una función de la librería estándar de C utilizada para "pedir" memoria al ordenador de forma dinámica, es decir, puedes utilizar almacenar más datos en tu programa cuando lo utilizas correctamente.

Volviendo a tu código:

> Funcionan los dos porque no tienes las suficientes banderas de advertencia activadas. :P

---

Nótese que `pi` es `int *`, lo cual es diferente de `int` y lo que haces con:

```
printf("%d", pi);
```

Es hacerle saber a la función `printf` que le estas pasando un entero, lo cual *en teoría* es cierto, pero estás invocando *al diablo*, digo, comportamiento indefinido al hacer esto, ya que no todas las plataformas definen `printf` de igual forma.

Al hacer:

```
printf("%d", *pi);
```

Le estás pasando a `printf` el valor correcto, lo que nos deja dicho que la forma correcta de asignarle valor *valor* a un puntero es utilizando el operador `*` antes del nombre de la variable:

```
*pi = 5;
```

Dependiendo del nivel del puntero y de su función.

Al hacer:

```
pi = 5;
```

Algunos compiladores se quejarán, otros no, pero es entendible, ya que al hacer eso de arriba le dices al compilador:

> Haz que el puntero `pi` apunte a la dirección de memoria `5`.

Lo cual será bueno y válido *(Para algunos compiladores, para otros no)*, pero al hacer:

```
pi = 5;
printf("%s", *pi);
```

Llamamos al diablo y ¡BÚM! Segmentation Fault, esto es debido a que la dirección de memoria 5`, no es válida dentro de la memoria asignada a tu programa.

Último punto, cuando haces:

```
char *cadena = malloc(5 * sizeof(char));
```

Y luego:

```
cadena = "hola";
```

Andas robando memoria *(Que se vuelve imposible de recuperar a menos que haya otro puntero con la misma dirección)*, debido a que la asignación de cadenas en C no funciona así, para ello debes utilizar alguna de las funciones dadas por la librería de C o crear tu propia función que copie los caracteres desde el inicio hasta la longitud del string:

```
char *cadena = malloc(5); // Es lo mismo.
sprintf(cadena, "%s", "hola");
```

Con lo anterior o utilizando la función `strcpy` tendrás el resultado que esperas.

> Nota: Las cadenas en C, o son arrays de caracteres o son punteros a caracter, por lo que si haces: `*cadena = "hola";` no estás asignando el valor a un puntero a caracter, sino a un caracter como tal y el compilador si te va a advertir sobre mal uso de literales.

Un último inciso que hay que aclarar es que al final del ciclo de vida de cada puntero cuya dirección proviene de una de las funciones para colocar memoria, siempre debe llamarse a `free` pasando dicha variable como argumento, para librerar esa memoria pedida anteriormente.

Con respecto a tu pregunta "Es correcto el código?":

El código es correcto de sintaxis, pero la lógica no va con el estilo de C; C es un lenguaje más cercano a la máquina, por lo que no hay tantas facilidades como en otros lenguanes de programación.

Saludos :)

Comment: @NaCI gracias por la respuesta tan clara, me podrias decir si el codigo que he añadido esta bien? un saludo y gracias

Comment: Yo lo veo bien :)