# ¿Cómo funcionan los punteros en C?

Tags: c

En un ejercicio se me pide, dada una nota y un incremento, que la función me devuelva la suma de la nota y el incremento, pero que ese resultado esté en la variable nota pero modificada.
Entiendo con eso que se debe utilizar los punteros, pero no entiendo cómo.
¿Alguien me sabría explicar un poco?

Comment: Bienvenido, es importante realizar preguntas en base a el documento [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), **te sugerimos editar tu pregunta y agregar lo que has tratado o investigado**. No olvides realizar el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) del sitio para conocer su funcionamiento básico, saludos.

Comment: ¿Cual es tu duda? Tu pregunta es amplia. Deberías de modificar tu pregunta y detallar la inquietud de una manera especifica.

Comment: Posible duplicado: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/66099/c%c3%b3mo-funcionan-los-apuntadores?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Un puntero guarda la dirección de memoria (algo como 0x601240) donde se encuentra el valor de la variable definida. El uso de punteros es últil a la hora de optimizar código ya que en algunos casos puedes operar solo con el puntero a la hora de elegir que valor guardado en memoria devolver.

Los punteros se declaran usando '*'.

Las dirección de memoria de las variable se puede obtener usando '&'.

Y cuando usas '*p = a' estas guardando a en la dirección de memoria guardada en el puntero.

Puedes probar este código para que te ayude:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void sumarNota(int a,int b, int *p);

int main(){
     int nota=5;
     int inc=2;
     sumarNota(nota,inc, &nota);
     printf("Resultado: %i ",nota);
     return 0;
}
void sumarNota(int a,int b, int *p){
 *p = a + b;
}
```